# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-io, byte

After writing the following code, am getting the error as **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

```
FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
long FileSize;
FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[] { (((int)(FileSize)) - 1) };
```

Help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Solution: (Thanks to p.s.w.g)

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[FileSize];
```

Solved the issue. As p.s.w.g suggested I've changed the value to 4096 in order to use the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: (((int)(FileSize)) - 1) why would you want to convert this to byte array?

Comment: code makes no sense. Solve by closing!

Comment: @Dineshkumar explain what you are trying to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to initialize a byte array of size `FileSize`. The syntax you want is this:

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[FileSize - 1];
```

However, this will actually create a buffer that's one-byte shorter than the file. You probably intended to do this:

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[FileSize];
```

Of course, you almost certainly don't want to buffer the *entire file*—otherwise it wouldn't be called a buffer. Unless you really need to, I'd suggest keeping your buffer size down to something more modest (say 4096) or reading it into a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instead.

**Further Reading**

- [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:->

```
byte[] Buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(FileSize-1);
            Array.Reverse(Buffer);
            byte[] result = Buffer;
```